# Javascript not functioning inside active_admin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, activeadmin

So I'm building a little set of Markdown helpers for an ActiveAdmin Form. I just have the italics one so far.

```
#form.html.erb
# ... some form code
    <%= link_to "i", "#", :class => "btn", :id => "italics_button" %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
# ... rest of form omitted
```

Which gives me the button with an ID of "italics_button" and a textarea with an ID of post_body. So far, all is well.

Now I have a coffeescript file to handle the wrapping the selected text in a given tag.

```
#posts.js.coffee
wrapText = (elementID, openTag, closeTag) ->
  textArea = $("##{elementID}") #select the text area
  len = textArea.val().length #total length of the text area
  start = textArea[0].selectionStart # start of the selected text
  end = textArea[0].selectionEnd # end of the selected text
  selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end) # The selected Text
  replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag # string with the selected text wrapped in the bbcode
  textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0,start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len)) # perform the replacement

$('#italics_button').click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  wrapText('post_body', '*', '*')
```

I'm fairly confident this code is okay, because I ripped it out of a project from a couple months ago where I did the same thing on a normal non-AA form.

I've updated the initializer to bring in the custom javascript:

```
# active_admin.rb
# rest of file omitted
config.register_javascript 'posts.js.coffee'
```

And finally, I can see on the New Post page in Active Admin, the javascript file is included and compiled.

However, the javascript event does not appear to be called. When I click #italics_button, the page attempts to follow the link to "#" and the javascript does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be executed as soon as the browser sees it:

```
$('#italics_button').click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  wrapText('post_body', '*', '*')
```

Your CoffeeScript will probably be loaded in the page's `<head>` element so there probably won't be any `#italics_button` in the DOM when you `$('#italics_button').click(...)` so no callback will be bound.

You can try the usual "run when the document is ready approach":

```
$ ->
  $('#italics_button').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    wrapText('post_body', '*', '*')
```

or you could use a "live" handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#italics_button', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    wrapText('post_body', '*', '*')
)
```

The latter will be useful if the `#italics_button` will be added dynamically after the server has sent the page to the browser.

Comment: Ah I see. In my other app the script gets loaded at the bottom so the element already exists, but in this case AA loads it up top before anything has been rendered.

Comment: @DVG: Right. Using `$ ->` to wrap your initialization stuff is a good idea anyway, that way you don't have to worry about where your (Java|Coffee)Script is in the page.